# ArcGIS Pro Add-In, MVVM getting filepath in viewmodel but showing only filename in view

Tags: add-in, arcgis-pro-sdk, model-view-viewmodel

I have an ArcGIS Pro Addin that I need to get a path to gdb for some processing, I would like to do this but show only gdb name in text box. I have a behaviors class and a viewmodel and a view. I tried catching the name as a property in the behaviors class but I am not getting the value when I bind to a text box to check for output. 
Here is the browser dialog

```
namespace BasemapCreator.Behaviors
{
    public class FolderDialogBehavior:Behavior<System.Windows.Controls.Button>
    {

        public void FolderBrowserDialog()
        {


        }
        public string SetterName { get; set; }

        protected override void OnAttached()
        {
            base.OnAttached();
            AssociatedObject.Click += OnClick;
        }
        protected override void OnDetaching()
        {

            AssociatedObject.Click -= OnClick;
        }
        private void OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            var dialog = new FolderBrowserDialog();
            var result = dialog.ShowDialog();
            if (result == DialogResult.OK && AssociatedObject.DataContext != null)
            {
                var propertyInfo = AssociatedObject.DataContext.GetType().GetProperties(System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public)
                    .Where(p => p.CanRead && p.CanWrite)
                    .First(p => p.Name.Equals(SetterName));

                string dirName = new DirectoryInfo(dialog.SelectedPath).Name;
                FolderName = dirName;
                _fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(dirName);
                FileName = _fileName;
                ArcGIS.Desktop.Framework.Dialogs.MessageBox.Show(FileName.ToString());
                propertyInfo.SetValue(AssociatedObject.DataContext, dialog.SelectedPath, null);
            }
        }
        private string _folderName;
        public string FolderName
        {
            get { return _folderName; }
            set
            {
                if (value != _folderName )
                {
                    _folderName = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("FolderName");
                }
            }

        }
        private string _fileName;
        public string FileName
        {
            get { return _fileName; }
            set
            {
                if (_fileName != value)
                {
                    _fileName = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("FileName");
                }
            }

        }
        private string _styleName;
        public string StyleName
        {
            get { return _styleName; }
            set
            {
                if (_styleName != value)
                {
                    _styleName = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("StyleName");
                }
            }
        }

        private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyname)
        {
            OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyname));
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs args)
        {
            var handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
                handler(this, args);
        }

    }
}
```

Here is the Binding in the View

```
<TextBox x:Name="gdbName" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="30" Margin="56,29,0,0"  Text="{Binding FolderName, Mode=TwoWay}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="282" AllowDrop="True">
        </TextBox>
```

And in the ViewModel I have the FolderName property

```
private string _folderName;
        public string FolderName
        {
            get { return _folderName; }
            set
            {
                _folderName = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("FolderName");
            }
        }
```

everything works but the pathnames are so long that sometimes they are hidden. I would like to show gdb name and pass complete path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution that works it was provided to me on another forum,'

Here is the property I created for the short name.

```
public string ShowName => Path.GetFileName(_name);
```

Then set it when the full path is passed

```
private string _name;

public string Name
{
    get { return this._name; }
    set
    {
        SetProperty(ref this._name, value, () => Name);
        SetProperty(ref this._showName, value, () => ShowName);
    }
}
```

In the viewmodel I have the property as well I also create the Model object so that the values can be passed

```
public CommonUseWindowViewModel()
{
   DisplayFolderName = new Model();
   Build = new DelegateCommand(ClickedMethod);
}
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
public Model DisplayFolderName { get; set; }
public string Name
{
    get{ return DisplayFolderName.Name; }
    set
       {
         DisplayFolderName.Name = value;
         OnPropertyChanged("Name");
         OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ShowName));
       }
 }
```